# JavaScript - Dropdown value dependent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two dropdown right now. I want to when the user selects "NO" the other automatically selects "YES" and vice versa.

I'm assuming I use JS here to make this occur, but not sure where to start. Below is my dropdown html code. If someone could help me get started, it would be helpful.

Code:

```html
 <div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
    <select id="cmicrophone" name="cmicrophone">
     <option value=" " selected = "selected"> </option>
     <option value="on">ON</option>
     <option value="off">OFF</option>
    </select>
   </div>    
   <div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
    <select id="microphone" name = "microphone">
     <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
     <option value="on" >ON</option>
     <option value="off">OFF</option>
    </select>
   </div
```

Comment: Add a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event handler to your `<select>` items. Then you can use an `if-else` to change the value of each of them and set them accordingly with `.value`.

Comment: Remember to upvote (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a same class to each `select` element and bind `change` event listener.

```js
$('.elem').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'on') {
    $('.elem').not(this).val('off');
  } else {
    $('.elem').not(this).val('on');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cmicrophone" id="cmicrophone">Currently:
  <select id="cmicrophone" class='elem' name="cmicrophone">
    <option value="" selected = "selected"></option>
    <option value="on">ON</option>
    <option value="off">OFF</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="microphone" id="microphone">Microphone:
  <select id="microphone" class='elem' name="microphone">
    <option value="" selected = "selected"></option>
    <option value="on">ON</option>
    <option value="off">OFF</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @catung555555 Import `jQuery` before your script and make sure you are importing all scripts at the bottom of the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point might be [listening for changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) on one select, and when the `change` happens, [selecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) the other `<select>` and [setting the right value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS solution (no jquery required).

The idea here is to:

1. select both `<select>` elements and save them into variables to refer to later using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. add [input event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) on both elements that call a function to handle the event
3. then use inside the function [`selectElement.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) to check the selected index of one element and use that to set the value of the other.

```js
// select the `<select>` elements
const cmicrophone = document.querySelector('#cmicrophone');
const microphone = document.querySelector('#microphone');

// define function to handler the events
function inputHandler(thisSelect, otherSelect) {
  if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 1) {
    otherSelect.selectedIndex = 2;
  } else if (thisSelect.selectedIndex == 2) {
    otherSelect.selectedIndex = 1;
  } else {
    thisSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    otherSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
}

// add event listeners that will 'fire' when the input of the <select> changes
cmicrophone.addEventListener('input', event => {
  inputHandler(cmicrophone, microphone);
});

microphone.addEventListener('input', event => {
  inputHandler(microphone, cmicrophone);
});
```

```html
<div>Currently:
  <select id="cmicrophone" name="cmicrophone">
    <option value=" " selected = "selected"> </option>
    <option value="on">ON</option>
    <option value="off">OFF</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>Microphone:
  <select id="microphone" name="microphone">
    <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
    <option value="on" >ON</option>
    <option value="off">OFF</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

One more thing to add: You assigned the same value to multiple `id`s. You should only assign one unique `id` per element.

Comment: this is a stupid question, but when I used that in my code it didn't work. could you show me in a regular html formatted page

Comment: @catung555555 I'm not sure if I understand. This example is regular HTML. Maybe the issue is that I'm using ES2015 (newer javascript)? Try it again but don't use internet explorer. also check that there aren't any duplicate IDs

Comment: I'm using chrome right now, and there's no duplicate ids

Comment: @catung555555 is the script *after* the html? i.e. in the body after the HTML?

Comment: @catung555555 post a jsfiddle and i'll try to help